# Graph Is Empty..Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pycharm

Please I need to rectify this, as it started recently for some days now. My grapgh shows empty, even though everything seems to be Ohk. When I print X, its 'NaN that displays. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns',10000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000)
pd.set_option('max_seq_items',1000)

data=pd.read_csv('cost-revenue.csv')
print data.describe()
print data
X= DataFrame(data,columns=[' Production_Budget_USD'])
y= DataFrame(data,columns=['Worldwide_Gross_USD'])
print X

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.title('production_budget_usd Vs worldwide_gross_usd ')

plt.show()
```

The link to the csv file: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HSFKFO_lrosCOX9n4N9Xl8y7J_tgx5Nl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is something wrong with your code logic.  It's giving you none because ur dataframe has 2 columns and you are assigning one column name --> DataFrame(data, columns=[' Production_Budget_USD'])

Comment: Thank you very much, have been battling with this for days. AM just starting to learn coding. Please can you help me explain the function of the dictionary and 'inplace'? Is like this issue is only on Pycharm, as d former code works in Jupyter?

Comment: This code will work but won't give you output plot right? 
actually inplace is used when you want to do the changes in the original dataframe. If you don't then it will return copy of your dataframe.

Comment: data.rename(columns={'a': 'A''}, inplace=True) <--- will return None and modify the original Dataframe(data)
can be written as 
data = data.rename(columns={'a': 'A''})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns',10000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000)
pd.set_option('max_seq_items',1000)

data=pd.read_csv('cost-revenue.csv')
print data.describe()
print data

data.rename(columns={'production_budget_usd': 'Production_Budget_USD', 'worldwide_gross_usd': 'Worldwide_Gross_USD'}, inplace=True)
X= data['Production_Budget_USD']
y= data['Worldwide_Gross_USD']

print X

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.title('production_budget_usd Vs worldwide_gross_usd ')

plt.show()
```